# AngularJS service storing and updating data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a simple app that shows a list of people each with a link to an edit controller.  The edit controller gets the person by id.  Once the edit form has been submitted, the page is redirected back to the person list.

I have a method to update the service data in the callback after the server saves the person.  The method I use does in fact work, however, I wasn't sure if there was a better way to achieve this.  After much searching I haven't found a concrete answer so I wanted to reach out to the AngularJS community here for help.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bGEG/

```
var app = angular.module('peopleApp',[]);

app.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope,People) {
    People.getList().then(function(response) {
        $scope.list = response; // show list of people with a link to new route to edit
    });
});

app.controller('EditCtrl',function($scope,$location,$routeParams,People) {
    // edit route so get person by id
    People.getById($routeParams.id).then(function(response) {
        $scope.person = response.person;
    });

    // submit save person form and send back to person list
    $scope.savePerson = function() {
        People.savePerson($scope.person).then(function(response) {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    }
});

app.factory('People',function($http,$q) {
    var people = [];
    var people_q = $q.defer();

    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        people = response.data;
        people_q.resolve(people);
    });

    return {
        getList: function() {
            return people_q.promise;
        },

        getById: function(id) {
            return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        },

        savePerson: function(person) {
            return $http.post(url).then(function(response) {
                // find person in person array and remove them
                for (i=0; i < people.length; i++) {
                    if (people[i].person_id == person.person_id) {
                        people.splice(i,1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // add new person data
                people.push(response.data);
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is basically an approach I have used except I would make the PeopleService much more generic so it could deal with any object.  On another note ensure you use '===' instead of '=='.

Comment: Thanks for the input and correction on the comparison.

Comment: You could think about using a proper caching service like angular-cache to remove some code you have write.  This has the advantage of being able to do in-memory/localstorage based caching and item expiry - http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/

Comment: It looks pretty good to me. The only difference I might make would be to use a Service instead of a Factory if you only ever need one instance of the service as opposed to multiple returned instances potentially with a factory. It'll work either way but that would be the one change I'd make.